# Understanding Reference Frame of View Composed of Rotated Objects in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-zstack, swiftui-rotationeffect

I'm following [this SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes) and encountered an issue with the positioning of badgeSymbols in Badge.swift. Here's the relevant code:

Badge.swift: (where the repositioning is applied)

```
import SwiftUI

struct Badge: View {
    var badgeSymbols: some View {
        ForEach(0..<8) { index in
            RotatedBadgeSymbol(
                angle: .degrees(Double(index) / Double(8)) * 360.0
            )
        }
        .opacity(0.5)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            BadgeBackground()

            GeometryReader { geometry in
                badgeSymbols
                    .scaleEffect(1.0 / 4.0, anchor: .top)
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2.0, y: (3.0 / 4.0) * geometry.size.height) // <--------- this is the re-positioning, particularly the "y" component
            }
        }
        .scaledToFit()
    }
}

#Preview {
    Badge()
}
```

RotatedBadgeSymbol.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RotatedBadgeSymbol: View {
    let angle: Angle

    var body: some View {
        BadgeSymbol()
            .padding(-60)
            .rotationEffect(angle, anchor: .bottom)
    }
}

#Preview {
    RotatedBadgeSymbol(angle: Angle(degrees: 5))
}
```

BadgeSymbol.swift (less relevant -- the important thing is that it is returning a view that is a path):

```
struct BadgeSymbol: View {
    static let symbolColor = Color(red: 79.0 / 255, green: 79.0 / 255, blue: 191.0 / 255)

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in
                let width = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height)
                let height = width * 0.75
                let spacing = width * 0.030
                let middle = width * 0.5
                let topWidth = width * 0.226
                let topHeight = height * 0.488

                path.addLines([
                    CGPoint(x: middle, y: spacing),
                    CGPoint(x: middle - topWidth, y: topHeight - spacing),
                    CGPoint(x: middle, y: topHeight / 2 + spacing),
                    CGPoint(x: middle + topWidth, y: topHeight - spacing),
                    CGPoint(x: middle, y: spacing)
                ])

                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: middle, y: topHeight / 2 + spacing * 3))
                path.addLines([
                    CGPoint(x: middle - topWidth, y: topHeight + spacing),
                    CGPoint(x: spacing, y: height - spacing),
                    CGPoint(x: width - spacing, y: height - spacing),
                    CGPoint(x: middle + topWidth, y: topHeight + spacing),
                    CGPoint(x: middle, y: topHeight / 2 + spacing * 3)
                ])
            }
            .fill(Self.symbolColor)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm puzzled why badgeSymbols needs repositioning in the ZStack, especially given that ZStack should center its children. I initially thought badgeSymbols as a composed object would be automatically centered.

My hypothesis is that the rotationEffect might be applied after the views are added to the ZStack. Is this correct? What's the underlying reason for this behavior?

I've attempted to 'flatten' badgeSymbols using Group {...} and tried adding .drawingGroup() modifier, but neither approach solved the issue.

Can someone explain why this repositioning is necessary and if there's a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the sample code uses `rotationEffect` to create 8 `BadgeSymbol`s that are rotated about their bottoms to different angles.

The key point here is that `ZStack` centres its views using the "logical" frames of the views, which is not affected by `rotationEffect`. Let's just consider the case of 2 `BadgeSymbol`s - one rotated 180 degrees, and one not rotated at all. Let the height of a `BadgeSymbol` be h. These two `BadgeSymbol`s will *appear* to have height 2 * h when combined in a `ZStack`,

[image]

but as far as the `ZStack` can see, these `BadgeSymbol`s have the same frame.

As a result, the `ZStack` puts the centre of the non-rotated `BadgeSymbol` in its centre, and the rotated `BadgeSymbol` appears below that. Here I've highlighted the frame of the `ZStack`, and its centre. The `ZStack` also has height h.

[image]

Notice that this is not quite what we want. We want the two `BadgeSymbol`s to be moved up a little, so that its "visual" centre is the same as the centre of the `ZStack`. This is why we need to change the position of the `BadgeSymbol`s. We want the badge symbols to have a logical y position of 0, instead of the default centre position (i.e. h / 2), essentially moving it up by h / 2.

In the code however, there is also a `scaleEffect`, with `anchor: .top`. Just like `rotationEffect`, this does not change the frames of anything - it's a purely visual effect. Now it looks like this (the red border represents the `ZStack` frame, as before)

[image]

Clearly, it should be shifted down by h / 4, and that's exactly what the code is doing. `geometry.size.height` is just "h". The y position is 3 * h / 4 because it's adding h / 4 to h / 2 (the position of the `BadgeSymbol`s otherwise).

In general, if the scale is 1 / n, then the position should be ((n - 1) / n) * h for it to be centred.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `.scaleEffect(1.0 / 4.0, anchor: .top)` in your `ZStack` scales the `badgeSymbols` while anchoring it at the top. This causes the subview to shrink towards its top, making it appear positioned towards the top of the view container, but in reality `badgeSymbols` is centred in the middle of `ZStack` and occupies all the available space that it needs, the scaling just makes an illusion that view has moved up. If you set `.scaleEffect(1.0 / 4.0)` without anchor and remove `.position` the `badgeSymbols` will be centered as expected.

Comment: `scaleEffect` is not the only cause. `rotationEffect` also has a non-center anchor. If both of these effects have a centre anchor, then it will indeed be centred, without needing to be repositioned.